# Find last element in a div and it's index in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

Double clicking on an image in the #train div will delete that image and all the images to thr right of it.
var d should return the last image in the train div and var g should return the index of that image in the main_pics array.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var main_pics = ["AN.gif", "BN.gif", "CN.gif", "DN.gif", "EN.gif", "GN.gif"];
    var starting_pics = ["AN.gif", "CN.gif", "EN.gif"];

    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < starting_pics.length; i++) {
        $("<img/>").attr("src", "images/" + starting_pics[i]).appendTo("#main").addClass("pics");
    }      
    // Code not relevant to the question.

    $("#train").on("dblclick", ".pics", function () {

        var l = $("#train").children(".pics").length;
        var c = $(this).index();
        $("#train").children().slice(c, l).remove();

        var d = $("#train").children(".pics").last()
        alert(d);
        var g = $.inArray(d.src.split("/").pop(), main_pics);
        alert(g);
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, what's your question?

Comment: var g returns an undefined error. Where does the object to string conversion go wrong?

Comment: Ah, I see. `d` is a jQuery object, not a DOM element, so it does not support the `src` property. Try `prop("src")` instead or access the underlying DOM element with `get()` or indexing.

Comment: I would like to avoid var d altogether and only have one line of code. Does "this" work with prev()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your fix:

```
var d = $("#train .pics").last();
var g = $.inArray(d.prop('src').split("/").pop(), main_pics);
```

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi, Sorry for the late post. MVP answered my question, so did you. Thank you both very much.